# Ignore text encoding change in SCM (svn, git etc.)

Tags: git, svn, character-encoding

Just like the title: is there a way to "ignore text encoding change in SCM (svn, git etc.)"?

For example: someone use gb18030 encoding scheme to commit files, when I checkout the files, I need to convert the encoding to be UTF-8, which makes SCM tools think it changed by me , which i am not indented to be.

Comment: because people working on different platforms tends to set different text encoding scheme by their editors. For example, people use VS in windows will use gb18030 for text encoding. Another working under OSX will see a batch of misleading words... but text encoding may not be allowed to change.

Answer (score 0):

No, differently encoded the same text-data is different binary-data